# JTextPane adding large spaces every time i insertString

Tags: java, html, swing, jframe, jtextpane

Hey i'm making a chat application and was at first using a simple JTextPane for a basic, color supporting, chat view pane. I then wanted to add html link support to make them clickable by adding an HTML listener and setting the content type to text/html. The clickable links work perfectly, but now every time i insert a String the chat will add a large space. Here is the code i use below:

Constructor:

```
    public JTextPaneTest() {
    this.addHyperlinkListener(new LinkController());
    this.setContentType("text/html");
    this.setEditable(false);
    }
```

Here is how i append regular text:

```
    public void append(Color c, String s) {

    SimpleAttributeSet sas = new SimpleAttributeSet(); 

    StyleConstants.setForeground(sas, c);

    StyledDocument doc = (StyledDocument)this.getDocument();

    int len = getDocument().getLength();

    try {
        doc.insertString(len, s, sas);
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    setCaretPosition(len + s.length());
}
```

And Here is how i insertlinks

```
    public void addHyperlink(URL url, String text) {
    try {
        Document doc = this.getDocument();
        SimpleAttributeSet hrefAttr = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        hrefAttr.addAttribute(HTML.Attribute.HREF, url.toString());

        SimpleAttributeSet attrs = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        attrs.addAttribute(HTML.Tag.A, hrefAttr);
        StyleConstants.setUnderline(attrs, true);
        StyleConstants.setForeground(attrs, Color.blue);

        doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), text, attrs);
    }
    catch (BadLocationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }        
}
```

For whatever reason with the content type set to just basic text, i don't get this space issue.

Here are some pictures of it:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpMBB.png

In the picture, the Name is inserted, then :, Then the rest of the text.

Edit: For whatever reason the JTextPane is automatically centering my InsertStrings.

Edit2: Is it possible to remove the margin between the HTML inserted strings? I've been trying everything for hours on end and simply can't find a solution. Only possible solution i can think of is reformatting the text via getText/setText every time i insert a string to insure no margins are added..

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: Are you intending to post an MCVE any time soon?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson i added some more (Constructor). What else would you like me to add?

Comment: I guess this is unfixable? Every time i insert a new String, a HTML is created. The Strings that are inserted are then spaced away from eachother as if i had a margin. Any way to remove the margin? This is driving my crazy to the point were i'm about to switch languages...

Comment: It's not about what I'd 'like' but whether you want help, and if so, how much.  Now follow the link to the SSCCE and *read* the document carefully because uncompilable code snippets do not make for an MCVE/SSCCE!

Comment: Could you just answer this: How could i merge my inserted text? I understand each time i insert it's creating a new HTML layout and each have a massive margin which causes my text to look so far apart.

Comment: Or in other words how to remove large spaces between html elements

Comment: bob, I understand you think you just want a basic answer to a basic question so no SSCCE is needed, but what you're describing is not a normal behaviour, so please provide a SSCCE for us to make tests and explain you what's happening and how to fix it. Don't worry, it doesn't take as long as you may think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using just basic 'text' and using components for click detection.

To fix this issue i was having with HTML, i simply used

```
editorKit.insertHTML(doc, doc.getLength(), "html code", 0, 0, null);
```

Rather then inserting my code directly usings doc's 'insertString'

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inserting text ith attribute try to create a dummy element and replace it with outer HTML containing th link

```
 SimpleAttributeSet a=new SimpleAttributeSet();
 a.addAttribute("DUMMY_ATTRIBUTE_NAME","DUMMY_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE");
 doc.setCharacterAttributes(start, text.length(), a, false);

 Element elem=doc.getCharacterElement(start);
 String html="<a href='"+text+"'>"+text+"</a>";
 doc.setOuterHTML(elem, html);
```

Se working example [here](http://java-sl.com/tip_autocreate_links.html)